# Http OPTIONS request gets completely ignored by Play route config

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using Play 2.2.1. I have the following route configuration in my route file:

```
OPTIONS       /*path          controllers.Application.options
GET           /               controllers.Application.index
...some more routes
```

I have the following set up in the Applications controller:

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._

object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index())
  }

  def options = Action {
    Ok("").withHeaders(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" -> "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" -> "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" -> "Accept, Origin, Content-type, X-Json, X-Prototype-Version, X-Requested-With",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" -> "true",
      "Access-Control-Max-Age" -> (60 * 60 * 24).toString
    )
  }
}
```

When I try to test an OPTIONS request with curl, it gets completely ignored by play.

```
curl -X OPTIONS --include 'http://localhost:9000/foo/139'
```

I get this error back:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 7045



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Action not found</title>

...some more head junk

    <body>
        <h1>Action not found</h1>

        <p id="detail">
            For request 'OPTIONS /foo/139'
        </p>



                <h2>
                    These routes have been tried, in this order:
                </h2>

                <div>

            <pre><span class="line">1</span><span class="route"><span class="verb">GET</span><span class="path">/</span><span class="call">controllers.Application.index</span></span></pre>

... more routes but none of them are for the OPTIONS request
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do something with `*path` segment - even if nothing...

routes:

```
OPTIONS    /          controllers.Application.options(path: String ?= "")
OPTIONS    /*path     controllers.Application.options(path)
```

Action:

```
def options(path: String) = Action {
  Ok("").withHeaders(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" -> "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" -> "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" -> "Accept, Origin, Content-type, X-Json, X-Prototype-Version, X-Requested-With",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" -> "true",
    "Access-Control-Max-Age" -> (60 * 60 * 24).toString
  )
}
```

It works

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the changes but still not good. The alarming thing for me is that in the list of routes tried (in the 404 response) the routes with the OPTION verb is not even listed!

Comment: Maybe something wrong with redeployment? try to clean the app and run again

Comment: That was actually the problem. For some reason the routes file didn't get recompiled properly. Even though I quit the running play app and manually ran 'compile'. I had to do a 'play clean-all' and then start play again. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sometimes weird things happens ie. when changing git branch during working dev app, anyway it's rather rare case

Answer (score 1):

In your application.conf add this line:

`play.filters.enabled += "play.filters.cors.CORSFilter"`

You won't be required to set any other headers etc.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in the Java Equivalent of this, it is:

in your conf\routes:

```
OPTIONS    /          controllers.OptionsController.options(path: String ?= "")
OPTIONS    /*path     controllers.OptionsController.options(path)
```

in app\controllers, file OptionsController.java:

```
package controllers;

import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

public class OptionsController extends Controller {

    public Result options(String path) {

        return ok("").withHeaders(
                  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" , "*",
                  "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" , "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
                  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" , "Accept, Origin, Content-type, X-Json, X-Prototype-Version, X-Requested-With",
                  "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" , "true",
                  "Access-Control-Max-Age" , Integer.toString(60 * 60 * 24)
        );
    }
}
```