# post request returns No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present but actually header is set on server

Tags: angularjs

I send an angularjs $http post request to a java backend:

```
var url = 'http://192.168.88.245:9000/dologin';
$http.post(url, 
            {
                "email" : "admin@admin.com",
                "password" : "1"
            }, 
            {
                withCredentials: true
            }
        )
```

In response i get this error:

```
OPTIONS http://192.168.88.245:9000/dologin 
(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.88.245:9000/dologin. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

But when i use `Advanced Rest Client` extension for chrome and sending same request with it, Server send 200 OK. This is the header in rest extension response:

```
Response headers 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
Access-Control-Max-Age: 300
Content-Length: 1181
```

What is the difference in this two situations?

Comment: request can only be sent to the same host, i think you are running your script on `localhost` and sending request to `192.168.88.245:9000`

Comment: @madforstrength Yes i'm on localhost. But why the extension can send that request but $http can't?

Comment: Answers to this question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work

Comment: @madforstrength that's not correct, enabling CORS allows you to access x-domain, and without CORS enabled even sending request to same domain but different port is treated as x-domain i.e. post from localhost:80 to localhost:81
Morteza I think you might have misconfigured backend, what java be are you using?

Comment: @madforstrength Ok i'll read that. We use play framework.

Comment: In that case check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144788/enable-cors-in-java-play-framework-2-2-x

Comment: @maurycy our java developer says that these configurations are set in play framework.

Comment: I think somethink is wrong in angularjs post, Because of `OPTIONS` word is red in console (i have written it in error: `OPTIONS http://192.168.88.245:9000/dologin`)

Comment: Is there a chance that cache is involved?  Did you tried incognito/private mode?

Comment: @maurycy No. Tested in opera, firefox and chrome's incognito.

Comment: I've checked the Advanced Rest Client, and it's not sending `OPTIONS` request, are you sure you return `200 OK` for those requests?

Comment: @maurycy Yes. Even we changed something in response of server and we recieved it in Rest Client's response.

Comment: maybe check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20525178/http-options-request-gets-completely-ignored-by-play-route-config

Comment: @maurycy We have set these options in play. When Rest extension recives response with correct headers, I think problem should be in angularjs.

Comment: One last question: with advanced rest client you did both requests? I mean `OPTIONS` and `POST`?

Comment: @maurycy Oh, Problem is this. I didn't know that `OPTIONS` is a request type. But why type of request is options when i wrote `$http.post()` ?!

Comment: angularjs (and probably other frameworks too) do an `OPTIONS` request before i.e. POST, so in the OPTIONS response they receive list of which type can be done `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE` if the POST is on list then it will do the request, in `Advanced Rest Client` you can choose to send `OPTIONS` request, do the same request you did for `POST` and see the output, my guess is that `OPTIONS` aren't properly configured on your server side

Comment: @maurycy Aha. Thanks alot man! If you write this in an "answer", I'll made it green. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

angularjs (and probably other frameworks too) do an `OPTIONS` request before i.e. `POST`, so in the `OPTIONS` response they receive list of methods that can be done

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
```

if the `POST` is on the list then it will do the request, in `Advanced Rest Client` you can choose to send `OPTIONS` request, do the same request you did for `POST` and see the output, my guess is that `OPTIONS` aren't properly configured on your server side and when you do `POST` request with `Advanced Rest Client` it omits the `OPTIONS` step that fails for angular