# CORS Issue with Angular 4 App calling Play Framework Web App

Tags: angular, http, typescript, playframework, cors

I have a frontend application stack that is built on Angular 4 and Node.JS which is then calling a backend API built using the Play Framework. I have now problems with the CORS filter. I have enabled the CORS filter on my Play framework as below:

```
object MyController extends Controller {

    implicit class RichResult (result: Result) {
    def enableCors =  result.withHeaders(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" -> "*"
      , "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" -> "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD"   // OPTIONS for pre-flight
      , "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" -> "Accept, Content-Type, Origin, X-Json, X-Prototype-Version, X-Requested-With" //, "X-My-NonStd-Option"
      , "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" -> "true"
    )
  }

  def powerPlantDetails(id: Int) = Action.async {
    dbService.powerPlantById(id).flatMap {
      case None =>
        Future.successful(
          NotFound(s"HTTP 404 :: PowerPlant with ID $id not found").enableCors
        )
      case Some(powerPlantRow) =>
        Future.successful(
          Ok(Json.prettyPrint(
            Json.toJson(toPowerPlantConfig(powerPlantRow)))
          ).enableCors
        )
    }
  }
}
```

But when I call this endpoint from my Angular 4 app, I could see from my Play Framework's server logs that it is indeed coming in as an OPTIONS request:

```
[info] application - OPTIONS /powerPlants?onlyActive=false&page=1 took 0ms HTTP status >> 404
[info] application - OPTIONS /powerPlants?onlyActive=false&page=1 took 0ms HTTP status >> 404
```

Why is this? How could I ensure that my Angular 4 app is doing a GET and not OPTIONS?

EDIT: If I call my Play Framework app from the Advanced REST client in Chrome, I see the following:

```
 application - GET /powerPlants?onlyActive=false&page=1 took 25694ms HTTP status >> 200
(Access-Control-Allow-Origin,*)
(Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Accept, Content-Type, Origin, X-Json, X-Prototype-Version, X-Requested-With)
(Access-Control-Allow-Methods,OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD)
(Access-Control-Allow-Credentials,true)
```

And it can be seen that it in-fact is making a GET request but it fails to do this if I call the same end point from my Angular app which to me is strange!

Comment: I think CORS has to do an OPTIONS first to see the capabilities of the server with the returned headers.  Since it's returning a 404 I'm guessing that stops the request there before doing a GET.  Maybe you have some headers or content types that make it not a 'simple request'?  [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: I'm not having any special headers! I will update my post with all the headers that I set in my Play Framework!

Comment: Haven't used the play framework, maybe check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20525178/http-options-request-gets-completely-ignored-by-play-route-config) out?  Something from your angular app is causing it to not be a simple request so it is sending the OPTIONS preflight to check server capabilities, and your server is returning a 404 for the OPTIONS request.  I think you'll either have to figure out how to make it simple request (go through that CORS link carefilly) or get your server to handle the OPTIONS...

Comment: Getting my Play server to handle OPTIONS for a GET request is something that I will avoid. I had yet another Angular application which was making a request to the same endpoint in my Play server and that was getting through but this new Angular app seems to have problems!

Comment: However the only difference between the two is that in the new Angular app when I do the http.get(...), I set some headers. May be I will try removing them and give it a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure specifically about this problem, but if you are having issues making `CORS` request, then use this this [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) (Allow control Allow origin).

This will let you make `CORS` request without need to pass any extra parameter in `headers/config`.

> drawback for this is that, it doesn't work for `CORS patch request`.

Answer (score 0):

So seems like I have figured out the problem. This was my get function in my Angular app:

```
get(path: string, params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams()): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.api_url}${path}`, { headers: this.setHeaders(), search: params })
      .catch(this.formatErrors)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
```

And this was the setHeaders function:

```
private setHeaders(): Headers {
    const headersConfig = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'content-type'
  };
```

I had to remove this completely! So my get would now look like:

```
get(path: string, params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams()): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.api_url}${path}`, { search: params })
      .catch(this.formatErrors)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
```

I'm not sure if this is correct, but that indeed get rid of the problem! I can see from my Play server logs the following:

```
[info] application - GET /powerPlants?onlyActive=false&page=1 took 1539ms HTTP status >> 200
[info] application - GET /powerPlants?onlyActive=false&page=1 took 1549ms HTTP status >> 200
[info] application - GET /powerPlants?onlyActive=false&page=1 took 1607ms HTTP status >> 200
```

Comment: Ah, I think it's the 'Content-Type' per the [CORS docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).  The only allowed types are two for forms or 'text/plain'.  Since it's a GET request you shouldn't need it, it's the content type of data you're sending.

Answer (score 0):

You're aware that Play provides build-in CORS handling in the form of a filter ? See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/CorsFilter for the details.

That takes away the burden of manually dealing with CORS.